# AWS Import/Export and devpay

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Can i use the AWS Import/Export service with devpay bucket? Or it is only supported for Amazon S3 buckets?

Answer (score 0):

It looks unlikely given that they state:

> Amazon DevPay buckets and accounts are not supported. You must use your AWS account credentials and non-DevPay buckets when using AWS Import/Export.

However, I too would think it would be neat if it work, so if you find out it does... please update the stream..

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSImportExport/latest/DG/index.html?CHAP_GettingSetUp.html